# Unexpected token import in custom node environment

Tags: jestjs

I am getting a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` when using my custom class that extends `NodeEnvironment`. When not using a custom test environment, modern JavaScript - ES modules, etc. works fine.

I'm using node `8.11.1` and yarn `1.6.0`.

This is the full error:

```
$ jest --no-cache
FAIL  __tests__/math.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /home/user/workspace/web/jest-custom-environment-no-import/__tests__/_helpers_/environments/integration.js:1
    (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import NodeEnvironment from 'jest-environment-node';
                                                                  ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

      at node_modules/jest-runner/build/run_test.js:31:29
```

This is my `.babelrc`:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        },
        "shippedProposals": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

And the `jest` portion of my `package.json`:

```json
"jest": {
  "testEnvironment": "./__tests__/_helpers_/environments/integration.js",
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/", "/_helpers_/"],
  "verbose": true
}
```

The custom environment:

```js
import NodeEnvironment from 'jest-environment-node';

export default class IntegrationEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
  }

  async teardown() {
    await super.teardown();
  }

  runScript(script) {
    return super.runScript(script);
  }
}
```

I've also created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/j-klassen/jest-custom-environment-no-import) that demonstrates this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a sensible workaround using [esm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm). I created an additional file that loads esm, which loads my custom Jest environment.

My `package.json` now contains:

```json
"jest": {
  "testEnvironment": "./__tests__/_helpers_/environments/integration.index.js",
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/", "/_helpers_/"],
  "verbose": true
}
```

The file `./__tests__/_helpers_/environments/integration.index.js` contains:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-global-assign
require = require('esm')(module);

module.exports = require('./integration').default;
```

`./__tests__/_helpers_/environments/integration.js` remains unchanged.

A working example is found in the [esm branch](https://github.com/j-klassen/jest-custom-environment-no-import/tree/esm) of my original repo.